# How to update one-to-one relationship model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has a one-to-one relationship with the User. I created a form that creates the model, but if that form is submitted again it gives "UNIQUE constraint failed". How can i make it so the data gets updated instead of it trying to create a new one?

models.py

```
class Userprofile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True,)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
class Profile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userprofile
        fields = ['address', 'zip']
```

views.py

```
def changeprofile(request):
    form = Profile(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()
        return render(request, 'myaccount.html', {"Profile":form})
```

Comment: This question was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637697/django-orm-how-to-update-one-to-one-relation-field-value

Comment: I tried that already, it gives me invalid literal for int() with base 10: when i try c = Userprofile.objects.get(user= request.user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got this error `UNIQUE constraint failed` because you are trying to create a new user again which already existed in the Userprofile table OneToOne Field will always check whether the user is unique in the table `Userprofile.`

So if you want to update the profile. Your view should be like this:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def changeprofile(request):
    profile_instance = get_object_or_404(Userprofile, user=request.user)
    form = Profile(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile_instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.save()
        return render(request, 'myaccount.html', {"Profile":form})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^update-profile/$', views.changeprofile, name="changeprofile"),
```